# How to parse the output of git status and sent it to another program with a batch file under Windows?

Tags: git, batch-file

I want to capture the result of `git status -s` which will output something like this:

```
 M /path/to/modified/file.py
 M /path/to/another/modified/file2.py
```

The first 3 characters are to be removed. I want to have this:

```
/path/to/modified/file.py, /path/to/another/modified/file2.py
```

(take each line of `git status -s`, strip the first 3 characters and glue them with a comma on a single line).

I will then send that string to another program (as an argument) who will work on those files.

Is it possible to do that with a batch (.bat) file under Windows?

I saw that you can do a substring with something like `set str=%str:~3,10%` but I had not found how to capture the output of `git` and split by lines and get each line length...

Comment: Never machine-parse user-oriented Git output. Use machine-oriented Git output, i.e., run `git status --porcelain` or `git status --porcelain=v2`. Fortunately, currently, `--porcelain` and `-s` have almost identical meanings, so anything you've developed so far for `-s` will work with `--porcelain`. Still, use `--porcelain`, not `-s`; `-s` might leave color-changing escape sequences in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have `git` on my system and therefore this is untested, the result is based simply on the examples you have in your question.

The `for` loop will assign each of the results to a metavariable `%%i` in this case, first we strip of the first two characters  `M` and then append each result to a single variable. We then simply strip off the first two characters being a  `,`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('git status -s') do (
   set "tmp=%%i"
   set "tmp=!tmp:~2!"
   set "result=!result!,!tmp!"
)
echo %result:~2%
```

**Note**

`for` will only assign the results if they are from `stdout` and not `stderr`, So in this case it will assign error messages to the variable.